# Connecting balanced low impedance output with unbalanced high impedance input

Tags: signal, cables, output, input

I want to send the signal form my audio interface to the guitar pedal effect. I'll use interface's line out balanced output and plan to plug it in to the effect pedal which has high impedance unbalanced input.

Which cable should I use? TS, unbalanced jack, or TRS balanced jack?

Answer (score 0):

the connector selection: If your guitar pedal already exists, then it probably has TS unbalanced jack for normal guitar cable. There's nothing selectable. If you are going to build something, use the same, because then you can some day connect a guitar, if needed.

Your audio interface can output a little too much for normal guitar compatible input, causes overdrive distortion. In that case insert a 2 resistor voltage divider to attenuate the extra level off. You can well make a clearly marked special cable which has the needed resistors inside the connector.

The balanced output of the audio interface has 3 wires: hot(+). cold(-) and GND. If there happens to be an output transformer, you must connect differently than if there's not. The interface manual SHOULD tell what's the right connection to unbalanced input. My guess is connect hot(+) to the cable wire and connect GND to the cable shield. But it's as well possible that the manual orders you to have 2 wire+shield cable and connect one wire between hot(+) and the plug tip, another wire 
between cold(-) ad the plug sleeve. The cable shield should be connected either to output GND or also to plug sleeve. As said: See the original interface manual!

Comment: It's the interface is  tascam us2x2. I didn't find any information about this kind of connection in manual. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ronx I checked the manual from Tascam Downloads. There's really nothing about the right connection to unbalanced input. But the output level +4dBm is probably 1000% too much for guitar inputs. For a start leave cold(-) unused, connect the rest, insert a voltage divider , say 2,2kOhm resistor and 270 Ohm resistor to drop the output level. If you turn the level down in the software, you very likely waste a great part of the bit resolution.

Comment: @Ronx Of course it's possible that line out pot affects directly to the output signal, not via software. In that case no voltage divider is a must, only keep the line out volume down.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I needed that. The output I will take signal from (and send to TS input guitar pedal) will be TRS. As Tip and Ring both send information, won't leaving Ring unused cut my signal in half? How about connecting Tip and Ring from TRS to Tip from TS and sleeve to sleeve accordingly?

Comment: @Ronx leaving ring unused doesn't remove half of the information, tip and ring have the same signal, but the ring has it multiplied by minus one (=inverted). That's the balanced output. If you had a balanced input, there the ring version of the signal would be inverted again and an average would be calculated. All noise which is same in both wires would be cancelled. That's the reason for balanced signals. Your idea to connect tip and ring to the same at the other end is a short circuit + it cancels all audio.

Comment: Now I understood that. Thank you. However I saw that sometimes people connect ring with sleeve. What would it do with this setting instead of leaving Ring unconnected?

Comment: That can be needed if the balanced output has transformer. Otherwise there would be no output at all. Good transformers are expensive, so the balanced outputs are in affordable stuff actually operational amplifier outputs + few hundred ohm series resistors in hot(+) and cold(-) signals to make possible to use even TS guitar cables without loading the the opamp outputs  too much. There are many discussions about half-balancing. I do not believe them. before I have seen noise measurements. Until I see them, connecting ring and sleeve together in unbalanced input is for me like a guitar cable.

Comment: Hmm ok. So I guess my audio interface doesn't is transformless and I won't benefit from connecting ring with sleeve. What are the final thoughts here? Connect tip to tip ring left with no connection and sleeve to sleeve. Right? Also, would I damage something if I connected TRS output to TS input with plain TS cable? What would happen?

Comment: @Ronx Hmmm, "doesn't is transformerless.". = a little ambiquous.  Test having ring unconnected. If it works, let it be. There's series resistors (=output impedance is said to be at least 100 Ohms), so the other version should be harmless.

Comment: I'm sorry for this "doesn't" thing. It was either Autocorrect or I left something accidentally. I wanted to say "So I guess my audio interface is transformless". Ok now it all seems much more clearer! Thank you so much sir. I'm really happy you took time to help me. All the best man. :)